# How would a P2P "Collective Transaction" be implemented (to increase privacy)

Tags: transactions, client, privacy

[In this thread, Luke Jr mentioned Collective Transactions](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=24784.msg1308187#msg1308187) would be a way for clients to increase anonymity when issuing transactions.

- How would such an implementation work?

(Please provide technical details or references as available)

Answer (score 1):

Dark Wallet is probably the closest to actively implementing something along these lines in a client.

See:

https://wiki.unsystem.net/index.php/DarkWallet/Alpha#Mixing

> When sending, the transaction is sent to an internal mixer, that
>   starts announcing on the coinjoin channel, if another peer answers,
>   both will negotiate a shared transaction that includes both peers
>   inputs and outputs. If successful the final transaction will be sent
>   into the network.
>
> You can see how a transaction from the mixer looks
>   https://blockchain.info/tx/c38aac9910f327700e0f199972eed8ea7c6b1920e965f9cb48a92973e7325046

And also the multisig section that follows:

> Multisig funds are special bitcoin addresses that can be spent from
>   only by a number of participants signing the transactions. This means
>   accounts can be held among several people or devices, and several
>   signatures (above some threshold) will be needed to spend.